# How do I display the contents of js file retrieved from the server (using ajax and jquery) in my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Well I am trying to load and execute a js file using the following jquery function

```
$.getScript(url, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( textStatus );              // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.responseText );      // 200
  console.log( data);
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Well the requirement for me is to display the contents of js retrieved from server in my webpage. How do I do it?

Comment: Are you planning to allow the user to download the file or is it for storage purposes?

Comment: Its for storage purpose

Comment: So to display it in a web page or to store it on the users computer?

Comment: Its for both the purposes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle Demo to get js file](http://jsfiddle.net/b9EbY/3/)

```
function get_html_translation_table (table, quote_style) {
  var entities = {},
    hash_map = {},
    decimal;
  var constMappingTable = {},
    constMappingQuoteStyle = {};
  var useTable = {},
    useQuoteStyle = {};

  // Translate arguments
  constMappingTable[0] = 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS';
  constMappingTable[1] = 'HTML_ENTITIES';
  constMappingQuoteStyle[0] = 'ENT_NOQUOTES';
  constMappingQuoteStyle[2] = 'ENT_COMPAT';
  constMappingQuoteStyle[3] = 'ENT_QUOTES';

  useTable = !isNaN(table) ? constMappingTable[table] : table ? table.toUpperCase() : 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS';
  useQuoteStyle = !isNaN(quote_style) ? constMappingQuoteStyle[quote_style] : quote_style ? quote_style.toUpperCase() : 'ENT_COMPAT';

  if (useTable !== 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS' && useTable !== 'HTML_ENTITIES') {
    throw new Error("Table: " + useTable + ' not supported');
    // return false;
  }

  entities['38'] = '&amp;';
  if (useTable === 'HTML_ENTITIES') {
    entities['160'] = '&nbsp;';     entities['161'] = '&iexcl;';     entities['162'] = '&cent;';     entities['163'] = '&pound;';     entities['164'] = '&curren;';     entities['165'] = '&yen;';     entities['166'] = '&brvbar;';     entities['167'] = '&sect;';     entities['168'] = '&uml;';     entities['169'] = '&copy;';     entities['170'] = '&ordf;';     entities['171'] = '&laquo;';     entities['172'] = '&not;';     entities['173'] = '&shy;';     entities['174'] = '&reg;';     entities['175'] = '&macr;';     entities['176'] = '&deg;';     entities['177'] = '&plusmn;';     entities['178'] = '&sup2;';     entities['179'] = '&sup3;';     entities['180'] = '&acute;';     entities['181'] = '&micro;';     entities['182'] = '&para;';     entities['183'] = '&middot;';     entities['184'] = '&cedil;';     entities['185'] = '&sup1;';     entities['186'] = '&ordm;';     entities['187'] = '&raquo;';     entities['188'] = '&frac14;';     entities['189'] = '&frac12;';     entities['190'] = '&frac34;';     entities['191'] = '&iquest;';     entities['192'] = '&Agrave;';     entities['193'] = '&Aacute;';     entities['194'] = '&Acirc;';     entities['195'] = '&Atilde;';     entities['196'] = '&Auml;';     entities['197'] = '&Aring;';     entities['198'] = '&AElig;';     entities['199'] = '&Ccedil;';     entities['200'] = '&Egrave;';     entities['201'] = '&Eacute;';     entities['202'] = '&Ecirc;';     entities['203'] = '&Euml;';     entities['204'] = '&Igrave;';     entities['205'] = '&Iacute;';     entities['206'] = '&Icirc;';     entities['207'] = '&Iuml;';     entities['208'] = '&ETH;';     entities['209'] = '&Ntilde;';     entities['210'] = '&Ograve;';     entities['211'] = '&Oacute;';     entities['212'] = '&Ocirc;';     entities['213'] = '&Otilde;';     entities['214'] = '&Ouml;';     entities['215'] = '&times;';     entities['216'] = '&Oslash;';     entities['217'] = '&Ugrave;';     entities['218'] = '&Uacute;';     entities['219'] = '&Ucirc;';     entities['220'] = '&Uuml;';     entities['221'] = '&Yacute;';     entities['222'] = '&THORN;';     entities['223'] = '&szlig;';     entities['224'] = '&agrave;';     entities['225'] = '&aacute;';     entities['226'] = '&acirc;';     entities['227'] = '&atilde;';     entities['228'] = '&auml;';     entities['229'] = '&aring;';     entities['230'] = '&aelig;';     entities['231'] = '&ccedil;';     entities['232'] = '&egrave;';     entities['233'] = '&eacute;';     entities['234'] = '&ecirc;';     entities['235'] = '&euml;';     entities['236'] = '&igrave;';     entities['237'] = '&iacute;';     entities['238'] = '&icirc;';     entities['239'] = '&iuml;';     entities['240'] = '&eth;';     entities['241'] = '&ntilde;';     entities['242'] = '&ograve;';     entities['243'] = '&oacute;';     entities['244'] = '&ocirc;';     entities['245'] = '&otilde;';     entities['246'] = '&ouml;';     entities['247'] = '&divide;';     entities['248'] = '&oslash;';     entities['249'] = '&ugrave;';     entities['250'] = '&uacute;';     entities['251'] = '&ucirc;';     entities['252'] = '&uuml;';     entities['253'] = '&yacute;';     entities['254'] = '&thorn;';     entities['255'] = '&yuml;';
  }

  if (useQuoteStyle !== 'ENT_NOQUOTES') {
    entities['34'] = '&quot;';
  }
  if (useQuoteStyle === 'ENT_QUOTES') {
    entities['39'] = '&#39;';
  }
  entities['60'] = '&lt;';
  entities['62'] = '&gt;';


  // ascii decimals to real symbols
  for (decimal in entities) {
    if (entities.hasOwnProperty(decimal)) {
      hash_map[String.fromCharCode(decimal)] = entities[decimal];
    }
  }

  return hash_map;
}


function htmlentities (string, quote_style, charset, double_encode) {
      var hash_map = get_html_translation_table('HTML_ENTITIES', quote_style),
        symbol = '';
      string = string == null ? '' : string + '';

      if (!hash_map) {
        return false;
      }

      if (quote_style && quote_style === 'ENT_QUOTES') {
        hash_map["'"] = '&#039;';
      }

      if (!!double_encode || double_encode == null) {
        for (symbol in hash_map) {
          if (hash_map.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
            string = string.split(symbol).join(hash_map[symbol]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        string = string.replace(/([\s\S]*?)(&(?:#\d+|#x[\da-f]+|[a-zA-Z][\da-z]*);|$)/g, function (ignore, text, entity) {
          for (symbol in hash_map) {
            if (hash_map.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
              text = text.split(symbol).join(hash_map[symbol]);
            }
          }

          return text + entity;
        });
      }
    return string;
}

$(function(){
    $("#getjs").click(function(){
        var url="http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
    }
})
.done(function( data ) {

    $("#container").html("<pre>"+htmlentities(data) + "</pre>")

});


    });
})
```

Comment: this.get_html_translation_table is not a function

Comment: waiting for my jet :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
<textarea id="ta" style="border:0;"></textarea>

$.getScript( url, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
         $("#ta").val(data);
});
```

Comment: Not really.It displays undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpjs's file_get_contents function to get the content of a javascript file

http://phpjs.org/functions/file_get_contents/